# Javascript not creating closure from within a nested function?

Tags: javascript, closures

I've been futzing with this for hours, and I just can't figure it out. I can't seem to get JS to create a closure from within a nested function:

```
function outerfn(z) {

    var inner_a = function(y) {
        var inner_a_var = y+5;   // STEP 3: create a local variable in-scope for this function

        call_my_arg(function(x) {  // Shouldn't this capture inner_a_var in a closure? 
            inner_b(inner_a_var + x);   // only closure here is called outerfn and does not contain inner_a_var
        });
    };

    var inner_b = function(w) {
        console.log(w);
    };

    inner_a(z); // STEP 2: call my internal function
}

outerfn(1);  // STEP 1: get the ball rolling

function call_my_arg(fcn) { // simulate an event callback
    fcn(1);
}
```

I'm really not sure what's going on here. At STEP 3, Chrome's debugger shows that it created Closure (outerfn)  with the function inner_b. Note that inner_a is not in the closure.

When I simulate an event callback, I'm defining an anonymous function right there. At that point the local environment has inner_a_var. Given everything I understand about closures, this action should create a new closure called inner_a containing inner_a_var. It does not.

When I put a breakpoint in call_my_arg and examine fcn, the debugger just shows the outerfn closure. And of course when the function is called, I don't have access to inner_a_var.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

FWIW I'm testing this on Chrome 66

This is not an academic exercise. I came across this situation while building a jQuery widget, where outerfn is the _create function which then needs to set up event handlers, which it uses nested functions for to try to avoid pyramid hell and reuse some logic.

Comment: "outerfn" is not the name of the closure, it's the name given to the scope that you are closing over. Given that `inner_a` is not a named function, it might not show a name for that scope.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When I put a breakpoint in `call_my_arg` and inspect `fcn`, I can see `[Scopes]: Scopes[3]` (`0:
Closure (inner_a) {type: "closure", name: "inner_a", object: {…}}
1:
Closure (outerfn) {type: "closure", name: "outerfn", object: {…}}
2:
Global {type: "global", name: "", object: Window}`) - just as you expect

Comment: I'm a bit lost to what the question is. The code seems to work as I expect it to and as you expect it to. I'm also trying it in Chrome 66. EDIT: [here is what I see](https://i.imgur.com/eja9k18.png)